# Hiding some items while the specific items pops on mouse hover . how? i am practicing making a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

i want a *subMenu* appear as mouse hover on *products* while the other items(*Home & Contact*) hidden on mouse hover.
i'm practicing making a dropdown menu using html and css.
this is what i've tried `.products:hover .menuBar>li:nth-child(odd) {  display: none;}`

any help.. thanks

this is my code:

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
}

li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.menuBar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
  width: 700px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.subMenu {
  display: none;
}

.products:hover .subMenu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  left: 25%;
}

.products:hover .menuBar>li:nth-child(odd) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="menuBar">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li class="products">Products
      <ul class="subMenu">
        <li>Product A</li>
        <li>Product B</li>
        <li>Product C</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Adding [runnable code](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would make it easier for folks to help

Comment: @Rob Moll thank u for adding a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reached the limit of the css world, cause you try to select the parent element from a child `.products:hover .menuBar>li`. This is sadly with CSS3 not possible ...maybe in the further future with CSS4. So you have to do it with JavaScript. Here is a short example how it would work to you: https://jsfiddle.net/6n02zey4/

Comment: so.. there's no a way to make it work with all CSS3 Selector..

Comment: a link that you've posted really help me. thanks for a solutions

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use JS for interacting with the page. You can do it with css, but JS is better, because many of the properties needed for making this happen are not supported for all browsers, especially on mobile phones.

Comment: a poor thing is i even don't know how to do it with css, how can i then use js to make it work,, anyway thanks for replying and info

Comment: You should use the best tools for a project that you are building, and if you want to interact with the page, use JS, if you want to style your page, use CSS. I think that you shouldn't learn CSS to make a dropdown menu, you should learn CSS to style webpages first, than go in to some more advanced stuff.